# ! Font \milstd=milstd not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found

Tags: packages, texlive

I tried to install the [milstd](https://ctan.org/pkg/logic) package to use the logical gates.

I didn't know how to do it so I used [this tutorial](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Installing_Extra_Packages).

I didn't have any `.ins` or `.dtx` file so I started on step 3. I had a `.sty`, a `.tex` and a `.mf` files and I put all the files in `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/milstd`.

I use TeX Live so I entered `texhash`. I didn't know whether or not I had to update the font maps but even if there wasn't any `.map` file, I updated font maps with `updmap-sys --enable Map=mapfile.map`.

When I enter `kpsewhich milstd`, I get `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/milstd/milstd.tex` so I guess it was properly installed.

However, when I try to compile a document with `\INVr`, I get: `! Font \milstd=milstd not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.` What should I do to solve it?

Here is a MWE even if it won't be useful:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{sectsty}

\usepackage{doi}

\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{milstd}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style = apa, autocite=inline]{biblatex}



\usepackage{fullpage}

\edef\restoreparindent{\parindent=\the\parindent\relax}
\usepackage{parskip}
\restoreparindent

\makeindex


\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{Roman}



\chapterfont{\centering}

\pagebreak
\setcounter{page}{3}




\tableofcontents{}


\chapter{Introduction}

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\pagebreak


\section{Lorem}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

\section{Ipsum}


\section{Lorem2}


\chapter{Ipsum2}

\section{Lorem3}

\section{Ipsum3}


\section{Lorem4}



\INVr

\end{document}
```

Comment: the mf-file belongs into texmf-local/fonts/source but I would try to find something newer.

Comment: What do you mean by "newer"?

Comment: a newer font. This one is from 1991.

Comment: It was provided as is in the package. Which package should I use to insert logic gates?

Comment: I don't know sorry, check e.g. https://ctan.org/topic/electronic

Answer (score 0):

Put the `.mf` file in the `texmf-local/fonts/source` folder. Don't add it in `/usr/local/texlive/year` to avoid overwriting the default files now or your files when updating.